# I hold a refugee travel document (Romania), do I need a visa to visit Sweden/Germany?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, sweden, refugees

I have Travel document convention 1951 issued by Romania, do I need a visa to visit Sweden or Germany?

Comment: @Dorothy I don't agree that this is a duplicate, because the other question asks generally for Schengen. I would vote to close if the answer over there was the same for all of Schengen. However, the answer in that other question was that it depends on the country, etc. Therefore, I think it's fine to ask for specific countries like OP has done. I certainly don't see OP's question answered in that other question/answer. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @Fiksdal; no problem; I based it on the Romania tags of the earlier question, and that this OP notes that his/her document was issued by the same country.

Comment: @Dorothy Yeah, but I'm talking about the countries OP wants to travel *to*.

Comment: Do you also have a residence permit for Romania?  Have you lived long enough in Romania so as to acquire a right of permanent residence?

Comment: I don't mean to duplicate questions but this topic is quite specific. I have temporary residence in Romania, I lived in Romania for 8 months by now.